# Email auto-forwarded from Google Apps to Gmail from website contact form are marked as spam

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

The contact form on my personal website sends mails to my Google Apps email (`@domain.com`) configured with that domain. In this email account, it arrives in the inbox (not spam). I have my `@domain.com` email setup to forward to my personal Gmail account so that I can check everything in one place. In my `@gmail.com` account, these messages from the contact form are marked as spam. In my`@gmail.com` account, I have also setup "Send mail as" for my `@domain.com` email as suggested [by Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en&ctx=mail&expand=5). Regular messages sent to the `@domain.com` email get forwarded to `@gmail.com` as expected and not sent to spam.

I will not accept answers suggesting me to mark as "not spam" in my Gmail account. This is also a problem that I have on a commercial website with the same contact form and Google Apps email setup. I wish to know why this is being sent to spam.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your domain's MX record(https://support.google.com/a/answer/33352?hl=en&ref_topic=2683820) is up to date. Also it wouldn't hurt to configure an SPF record for your domain(https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en&ref_topic=2759192). These are things that can lessen the chance of your domain's outgoing email to be labelled as spam.

Comment: My hosting service (Dreamhost) configures the google apps MX records automatically and doesn't allow me to change them. (I can view the records however.) I just configured the SPF record (DNS is still updating) but I don't understand how the email would make the inbox in one google account but be spam in another (after forwarding).

Comment: Per Google:

The authentication process tries to verify the real sender by looking at a message's authentication data. This data should be included in a message's "signed-by" or "mailed-by" headers (shown beneath the subject line when you look at a message's details). When the sender doesn't include this data, we can't be sure whether or not the message was forged. For example, a message might claim to be from a Gmail address, but we can't confirm that claim if the message doesn't have authentication data.

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1366858?hl=en